# Dealing with data that is already semi-summarized in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have been given a dataset of births in my county that is in a format that has me scratching my head. Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(Race_Ethnicity = c("Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "White", "White", "White", "White"),
                 Birthweight_Grams = c("2000-2499", "3000-3500", "3500-4000", "4000-5000", "2000-2499", "3000-3500", "3500-4000", "4000-5000"),
                 Total_Births = c(345, 731, 245, 678, 934, 567, 845, 876)
                 )
```

I then added a new column for low birth weight vs normal birth weight:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Birth_category = ifelse(Birthweight_Grams %in% c("1000-2000", "2000-2499"), "Low_birthweight", "Not_low_birthweight"))
```

Which produces a table that looks like this:

```
  Race_Ethnicity Birthweight_Grams Total_Births      Birth_category
1        Hispanic         1000-2000          345     Low_birthweight
2        Hispanic         2000-2499          731     Low_birthweight
3        Hispanic         3000-3500          245 Not_low_birthweight
4        Hispanic         3500-4000          678 Not_low_birthweight
5        Hispanic         4000-5000          934 Not_low_birthweight
6           White         1000-2000          567     Low_birthweight
7           White         2000-2499          845     Low_birthweight
8           White         3000-3500          876 Not_low_birthweight
9           White         3500-4000          764 Not_low_birthweight
10          White         4000-5000          623 Not_low_birthweight
```

What I would like to do is visualize the proportion (i.e. a percentage) of total births per ethnicity that was low-birth weight vs normal birth weight. But because the data is already semi-summarized (i.e. not one observation per row) I am really struggling. Any help much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the percentage of `Total_Births` in each `Race_Ethnicity` and then use the data to plot it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(Race_Ethnicity, Birth_category) %>%
  summarise(Total_Births = sum(Total_Births)) %>%
  mutate(Total_Births = prop.table(Total_Births) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Race_Ethnicity, Total_Births, fill = Birth_category) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]